# Agrupar por valores específicos de coluna em um DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Tenho o seguinte dataset:

```
    Brand   Condition   Fuel    
0   Toyota  Used    Diesel  
1   Suzuki  Used    Petrol  
2   Suzuki  Used    CNG 
3   Suzuki  Used    Petrol  
4   Toyota  Used    Petrol
```

São mais de 10 mil registros e tem mais de 15 marcas. 
Como eu filtro, por exemplo, somente as linhas com Brand igual a Toyota?

Tentei o seguinte:

```
df1 = df.filter(items=['Brand','Fuel'], axis=1)
teste = df1.filter(like='Toyota', axis=0)
teste.head()
```

Mas não retornou nada.

Comment: Veja se não é isso que você quer fazer `result = df[  df['Brand'] == 'Toyota'  ]`

Comment: Exatamente isso. Obrigado, eu estava pensando da maneira mais difícil possível.